# generic fibre functor for relative rigid spaces

Tags: reference-request, rigid-analytic-geometry, formal-schemes, non-archimedean-fields

The classical theory of formal models of rigid analytic spaces due to
Raynaud introduces the category of admissible R-formal schemes for $R$ a
discretely valued ring, which includes locally topologically of finite
type formal R-schemes and so-called special formal R-schemes (covered
by formal spectra $\mathrm{Spf} R[[x_1, \ldots, x_n]]/(a_1, \ldots,
a_n)$). This category is localised with respect to blowups in the
special fibre and a "generic fibre" functor $\eta$ defines an
equivalence of categories between the localised category of admissible
formal $R$-schemes and the category of rigid analytic spaces over $K$.

It is natural to extend the formal scheme part of the construction to
formal schemes over more general base spaces, which was done by
Bosch and Luetkebohmert. The resulting generalised category is called by him "relative
rigid spaces", and the base space $S$ can be, in particular, an
admissible formal $R$-scheme. While the base scheme has a generic
fibre in the sense of Raynaud, I couldn't, to my surprise, find a
construction of generic fibre functor for *relative rigid spaces*
over $S$. I wonder if I overlooked a well-known fact, or if there is an serious obstacle to such construction. I expect that this fibre functor ought to give rigid analytic $K$-spaces fibred over an analytic space closely related to generic fibre of $S$.

For example, the universal Tate curve is naturally regarded as a relative rigid analytic space over $\mathrm{Spf}R[[q]]$, so the generic fibre of it should give rise to the rigid analytic universal family of totally degenerate elliptic curves over the punctured open disc (punctured is important, as the period $q$ cannot vanish).

My question is, therefore: has the construction of such generic fibre functor of relative rigid analytic spaces over admissible formal $R$-schemes been worked out in the literature?

Comment: Could you give a reference for relative rigid spaces? In your setting, if the base space $S$ is an admissible formal scheme, it seems to me that the existence of the generic fiber functor for spaces over $S$ follows from the funtoriality of the generic fiber functor.

Comment: By the way, I do not think that the equivalence of categories you wrote works in such a generality. You probably want to consider only formal schemes that are locally topologically of finite type.

Comment: @JérômePoineau: they are introduced in "Formal and rigid geometry. I. Rigid spaces." Siegfried Bosch; Werner Lütkebohmert
Mathematische Annalen (1993) Volume: 295, Issue: 2, page 291-318

I doubt that the answer is immediate from Raynaud's construction, as the example with the universal elliptic curve illustrates. While the relative rigid space is defined over a formal scheme with generic fibre open disc, the rigid analytic space is expected to only be defined over the punctured disc.

Comment: @JérômePoineau: wait, I was sure that formal completions along a closed subscheme of the special fibre have a well-defined generic fibre (so this includes special formal $R$-schemes). I believe there is a result due to Berkovich that the preimage of the closed scheme under the reduction map is the generic fibre of this formal completion.

Comment: Their generic fiber is certainly well defined as a Berkovich space. If the formal model is not topologically of finite type I suspect its generic fiber will not be strictly analytic. That being said, I believe you could define "special formal $S$ schemes" in a relatively straightforward manner (if it's not already in "Vanishing cycles for formal schemes II")and perform the localization. I recently had to chase through the specific localization construction they use and it really comes down to the blow up category being filtered. This should still be true by general nonsense about blow ups.

Comment: @DimaSustretov: In the example of the universal elliptic curve, I believe that you still get something over the point 0 in the disk, but not an elliptic curve.

Comment: @DimaSustretov: Generic fibers always exist, you are right (although in this generality, the construction is due to Berthelot and not Raynaud). I was only complaining about the equivalence of categories. Look at the open disk. You get a model of the form Spf $R[[T]]$ but can also get one (much more complicated and certainly not affine) that is locally topologically of finite type. You will not get from one to the other by blowing up and down.

Comment: @JoeBerner: The generic fiber is defined whatever the setting you want to consider (rigid spaces, Berkovich spaces, Huber spaces). And it is always strictly analytic.

Comment: @DimaSustretov: I should have said this before, but I think that the point of the construction is precisely to consider also base spaces $S$ for which no generic fiber exists (such as Spf $\mathbb{Z}[[q]]$ in the case of the universal elliptic curve). Otherwise I think it just boils down to functoriality as I said before.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You will find what you are looking for in Ahmed Abbes' 'Elements de Geometrie Rigide $I$', where rigid geometry a la Raynaud is developed in a relative setting. It is written in French, but it should cause no trouble to someone who has read the EGA's.

Comment: Dear js21, I have checked the Abbes' book and I found that the treatment there revolves around categories of formal schemes and their localisations. Relative rigid spaces are *defined* there to be objects of such localised categories, and there doesn't seem to be any functors into the category of rigid analytic space in the classical sense.

Comment: Is that not how Bosch and Luetkebohmert define relative rigid spaces? I'm looking at page 22 of http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/pdfcache/PPN235181684_0295/PPN235181684_0295___LOG_0022.pdf

Answer (score 1):

If you look at 1.1.12 in Huber's book "Étale cohomology of rigid analytic varieties and adic spaces" he notes that if you embed admissible Noetherian formal schemes into adic spaces, then the "analytic points" functor induces an equivalence of categories after localizing at admissible blowing ups. See the reference for a precise statement.